# which chart to use to show progress android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am making an Analytics page in android. I have a database in the following structure. There are 4 games with certain levels in it.:

Game Type:

- Tracing Alphabets - 10 levels
- Tracing curves - 20 levels
- Puzzle - 34 levels
- Quiz - 4 levels

This is example of the table structure I am having currently:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+
|  GameType  | CurrentLevel | Coins | Badge  | TimeStamp  | didPlay |
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+
| TraceAlpha |            1 |    10 |      0 | 10-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceAlpha |            2 |    10 |      0 | 10-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceAlpha |            3 |    10 |      0 | 11-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceAlpha |            4 |    10 |      1 | 12-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceAlpha |            5 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| TraceAlpha |            6 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| TraceAlpha |            7 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| TraceShape |            1 |    10 |      0 | 11-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceShape |            2 |    10 |      0 | 12-11-2017 | true    |
| TraceShape |            3 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| TraceShape |            4 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| Quiz       |            1 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| Quiz       |            2 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| Quiz       |            3 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| Puzzle     |            1 |    10 |      0 | 10-11-2017 | true    |
| Puzzle     |            2 |    10 |      0 | 12-11-2017 | true    |
| Puzzle     |            3 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
| Puzzle     |            4 |     0 |      0 | NULL       | false   |
+------------+--------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+
```

**Table structure Explanation:**

I have 4 games in my project. Every game has certain levels e.g: Puzzle has 34 levels and Quiz has 4 levels. Initially all the levels are locked except the 1st level. If the user complete 1st level(storing the timestamp when he completed the game as well) then 2nd level will be unlocked, and every level he plays, he will earn 10 coins. If the user has completed 4 levels of a certain game he will get a badge related to that game e.g: if he has played 4 Puzzle game levels. He will get a Puzzle badge. This is same for all the games.

Now I want to show a chart for individual games.

What can be the best charts that suits this kind of database structure?

More likely I want to show how many levels the user has completed in individual games.

Comment: I am not completely sure if you want to display data of one or more users. If you want to display the data of a single user just display the highest achieved level / gameType since you cant play higher levels without unlocking the previous. If you want to display the data for several users display the average achieved level / gameType.
Instead of displaying the raw value u could use a normal BarChart.
A Stacked Barchart or Combined BarChart could be nice too with Bars for each level and grouped by GameType.

Comment: I just want to display the user his/her progress only. No other users are involved.